# Mysql error 150 can't creat table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

In my lottery ER diagram designed in mysql workbench i used forward engineering option. But some tables are not generating. So when I use synchronized model with database option I'm having this error..

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'lottery.order' (errno: 150)

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lottery`.`order` (
  `o_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `lot_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `draw` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `inst_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `qty` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `bprice` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `total` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `profit` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`o_id`, `lot_id`, `draw`) ,
  INDEX `fk_order_d_draw1` (`lot_id` ASC, `draw` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_order_inst1` (`inst_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_d_draw1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`lot_id` , `draw` )
    REFERENCES `lottery`.`lot_draw` (`lot_id` , `draw` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_inst1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`inst_id` )
    REFERENCES `lottery`.`inst` (`inst_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

I don't know where to look. Please help me..

**After the first edition**

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'lottery.order' (errno: 150)

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `lottery`.`order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lottery`.`order` (
  `o_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `lot_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `draw` INT NOT NULL ,
  `inst_id` INT NULL ,
  `qty` INT NOT NULL ,
  `bprice` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `total` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `profit` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`o_id`, `lot_id`, `draw`) ,
  INDEX `fk_order_d_draw1` (`lot_id` ASC, `draw` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_order_inst1` (`inst_id` ASC) ,

    FOREIGN KEY (`lot_id` , `draw` )
    REFERENCES `lottery`.`lot_draw` (`lot_id` , `draw` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

    FOREIGN KEY (`inst_id` )
    REFERENCES `lottery`.`inst` (`inst_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed

Comment: Some errors are occured in the indexes. `CONSTRAINT` index field in the both tables must be equal, `lot_id` and `inst_id` must be indexes and so on. Remove first or second constraint (or both) and run your query again. If the query would be successed then error in your constraints. Show create statement for this tables

Comment: @Andrey Bakharev i added it to question.. please take a look..

Comment: You do not understand me. You must not remove the word CONSTRAINT, you must remove CONSTRAINT index completely (first, second, or both) and check the results.

Read this: [foreigh keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) and [foreigh keys in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: MySQL automatically creates the index for a foreign key since version 4.1. The errno 150 happens if the columns in the referenced table have different data types that the foreign key columns in `order`, or if the columns in the referenced table are not in a `KEY`. It should be a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE KEY`.